# How can I plot a graph which contains duplicate nodes?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

For $n\leq 3$, the following code works as expected:

```
n = 3;
NestGraph[# + {1, 3, 5} &, 2, n - 1, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

For $n=4$, I want to get a graph looks like this, but the code no longer works as expected, even when I try to change `GraphLayout`.

I think it may be because of the duplicate node in the graph. So, is there a proper way to generate the following graph?

[image]

For $n=5$

[image]

Comment: Are the vertices labeled 5 the same or distinct? (Ditto for the other duplicate expressions.) Another way to put it, do you want the graph or the graphics?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Both can be, graph is preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update 2:**

```
ClearAll[nG0]
nG0 = NestGraph[x |-> (F @@ (List @@ x + {#, 1}) & /@ {1, 3, 5}), 
    F[2, 1], #, 
    VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[v[[1]], Center]}, ##2, 
    VertexSize -> Large, VertexStyle -> LightOrange] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
nG0[#, ImageSize -> 1 -> 50] & /@ {3, 5} // Row
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[f, nG]

f = Apply[Join]@Map[(x |-> # + x) /@ Thread[{1, {1, 3, 5} }] &];

nG = NestGraph[f, {{1, 2}}, # - 1, 
    VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[v[[2]], Center]}, ##2, 
    VertexSize -> Large, ImageSize -> Large] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
nG[3, VertexLabelStyle -> 16, VertexStyle -> LightOrange]
```

[image]

```
Grid[Partition[nG[#, ImageSize -> 1 -> 40, 
     PlotLabel -> Style[PromptForm["n", #], 16, Black]] & /@ Range[2, 7], 2], 
   Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> "13.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (November 22, 2021)"

**Update:** For versions before v13.0:

```
ClearAll[edgeList, graph]

edgeList = Rest @*Flatten @
    NestList[Flatten @* Map[(x \[Function] DirectedEdge[#, # + x]) /@ 
         Thread[{1, {1, 3, 5}}] &] @* DeleteDuplicates @*
      Map[Last], {0 -> {1, 2}}, # - 1] &;

graph = Graph[edgeList[#], 
    VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[v[[2]], Center]}, ##2, 
    VertexSize -> Large, ImageSize -> Large] &;
```

***Example:***

```
graph[7]
```

[image]

Comment: Thansk, but it doesn't works on version 12.x.

Comment: @expression, please see the update for versions older than 13.0.

Answer (score 5):

Not pretty, but it works

```
NestGraph[Function[x, C @@ (List @@ x + {1, #}) & /@ {-1, 0, 1}], 
  C[0, 2], 3, VertexLabels -> C[x_, y_] :> 3 x + 2 y - 2]
```

[image: graph]

Here `C` is used as an artificial wrapper to represent a 'point', since using bare lists would mess with both the initial specification of `C[0,2]` and the function nesting.

As Michael E2 hints, it's not possible for graphs to have multiple of the same vertex -- just like in set theory sets can't have multiple elements.  So in this graph I'm using the `Label`s to superficially give some vertices the same name: internally, each vertex is indexed by a unique point (it's cartesian coordinate, in these layouts).

---

When `n=7`,

```
NestGraph[Function[x, C@@(List@@x+{1,#})& /@ {-1,0,1}], 
  C[0,2], n-1, VertexLabels -> C[x_,y_]:>3x+2y-2]
```

yields

[image: graphbig]